# How to preg_match with the pattern being an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

Php.net had this preg_replace snippet

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Is there a way to run a preg_match on $patterns in order to do something like this

if preg_match found in $string then preg_replace else echo no matched found

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all you want to do is have a `preg_replace` that also alerts you to matches that didn't happen?

The following will work for you:

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/pig/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';

for($i=0;$i<count($patterns);$i++){
    if(preg_match($patterns[$i], $string))
        $string = preg_replace($patterns[$i], $replacements[$i], $string);
    else
        echo "FALSE: ", $patterns[$i], "\n";
}
echo "<br />", $string;

/**

Output:

FALSE: /pig/
The slow black fox jumped over the lazy dog.
*/
```

---

```
$string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string, -1, $count);
if(empty($count)){
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Comment: It does work. I have tested it and showed the output.. What are the actual input and pattern/replacement arrays that you're working with?

Comment: It works in a sense. The whole point is to replace strings found in $patterns with strings from $replacements. Your code echoes out $string as is without replacing anything. For example the original code outputs, "The bear black slow jumped over the lazy dog." It replaces any found strings from the $patterns array and replaces them with the corresponding word from $replacements.

Comment: Ha, ahh sorry, my bad.... I forgot to add in the `$string =` before the `preg_replace`!

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. But I think you misunderstood my op. I don't want to know what matches were not found I just want to know if a match was found period. If match found then replace. If no match found tell me there was no match found. I don't need to know that pig or any other specific word in the array was not found. See what I mean?

Comment: Okay, firstly, see updated answer (and _my_ comment above)... Secondly, so all you want to know is whether `preg_replace` has replaced anything?

Comment: Exactly. That is all I need done. Just can't get preg_match to work.

Comment: See the _again_ updated answer... Replace the `for{}` in the original with the update. It will tell you if no matches were found **OR** do the replacements and apply them to `$string` so when you `echo $string` it will show with the replacements :)

Comment: Brilliant, didn't think to use `empty()`. Very elegant. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad we got to the bottom of it :)

Comment: @stevenmw accept the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 1):

Is this you where looking for?

```
    $string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
  if (preg_match("/\b$pattern\b/", $string)) {
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $string);
      }
}
```

Comment: Tried that earlier. Doesn't work. Pretty sure you can drop the echo from preg_replace. Doesn't work with or without it.

Comment: That's still not going to work. Each pattern needs to be like `/quick/` I'd like to keep my array as is if possible. Maybe I can use implode or foreach?

Comment: That won't work because `preg_match` only accepts a `string` and you're feeding it an array...

Comment: That's why I edited using a foreach, forgot preg_match doesn't use arrays..

Comment: That's not going to work either... The pattern you're feeding the `preg_match` is incorrect and won't be accepted by the regex engine.